# Rails 4 trouble with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I'm trying the accepts_nested_attributes_for function. I am creating an inventory system and the accepts_nested_attributes_for feature is being used to attach multiple order details to an order. An order must also be associated with store location.

The problem I'm having is the order is being created but no data is being passed to the order details table.

My views are below:

**Orders View**

```
<h1>Place An Order</h1>

<%= form_for ([@location, @order]) do |f| %>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :customer_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <h3>Items</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :order_details do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'order_detail_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Item", f, :order_details %></p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Order_details_fields Partial**

```
<p class="fields">
    <%= f.label :item_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :item_id %></br>
    <%= f.label :quantity %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %></br>
    <%= f.label :cost %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :cost %></br>
    <%= f.label :discount %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :discount %><br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)" %>
</p>
```

**Orders Controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @orders = Order.all
    end

    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @order = Order.new
        @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    end

    def create
        @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
        @order = @location.orders.create(order_params)  
        #@order =  @order.order_details.create

        if @order.save
            redirect_to @order
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, order_detials_attributes: [:id, :item_id, :quantity, :cost, :discount])
        end

end
```

**Orders Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    has_many :order_details, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Order Details Model**

```
class OrderDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :locations do
      resources :orders
end

resources :orders do
      resources :order_details
end
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try adding this line to `new` method `@order.order_details.build`.

Comment: Can you post the `params` you receive from the form submission?

Comment: Hey Rick how would I get the params from the form submission

Answer (score 0):

**Build**

Looks like everything is right to me - the only problem being the issue `@Pavan` outlined, which is that when you use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), you have to `build` the associative object, so it can be used in the form:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
Class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @location = Location.find parmas[:id]
       @order = Order.find params[:id]
       @order.order_details.build
   end
end
```

Although this looks like the *only* issue you have, there may be other problems (validation on the `OrderDetail` model as an example (which you don't have)

The only issue with what both I and Pavan have recommended is if you don't build your associative data, the `fields_for` don't show on the form. If your fields are showing, it may be a different issue, which will be highlighted in the `params` hash

Comment: Ok I'll look into this and see what I can find. Rick above asked me to post the params from the form submission. How would I see this?